# Output domain name only based on full URL user input within a custom field

Tags: php, url, strip, domain-name, prepend

I'm not a programmer but I have basic understanding when it comes to modifying existing code.

I'm dealing with a User Generated Content website where end-users can fill out a form to post their content.

One of the custom fields within that form is meant to promote their website link.
Custom field: `cf_website` which I can output within the templates anywhere.

The theme that I am using automatically transforms the user's input text into a clickable link, what I am trying to do is to strip the `https://www` or whatever is prepended to the domain name in order to output only the `domain.com` as a link.

Ex:
User input = `https://www.example.com` or `http://www.example.com` or `https://example.com` or `www.example.com`
Output --> `example.com`

I know I will need to declare this function within the theme's `Functions.php` file (WordPress theme)

I've done some research online and found few links that seem to hint in the right direction although I can't find something that tackles the value of a specific custom field merge tag.

I have tried:

- [php.net/parse_url](http://php.net/parse_url)
- [geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-get-parameters-from-a-url-string-in-php/](http://geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-get-parameters-from-a-url-string-in-php/)

Any feedback/suggestions/hint would be appreciated.